# How to dismiss overflow menu when home button is pressed android?

Tags: android, kotlin, menu, android-menu, overflow-menu

I am displaying overflow menu list when we click the three dots. When I press home button and again when I launch the app, overflow menu list is still displaying. How to dismiss overflow menu list window?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        Log.v("RAMKUMARV ONCREATEOPTION", "RAMKUMARV");

        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        //  getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings);
        item.setVisible(true);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

[image: Attached image]

Comment: Hey @Shadow, Can you please add you menu xml file `menu_main` as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have an activity field that stores the options/overflow menu whenever the `onCreateOptionsMenu()` gets triggered, and then use [`close()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Menu#close()) method to dismiss the menu when the home button is clicked i.e. in `onUserLeaveHint()`.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    // Field to store the overflow menu
    private Menu mOverflowMenu;

    // omitted rest of your code

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        
        mOverflowMenu = menu;
        
        // omitted rest of your code
        return true;
    }
    
    // Dismissing the overflow menu on home button click
    @Override
    protected void onUserLeaveHint() {
        super.onUserLeaveHint();
        mOverflowMenu.close();
    }   
    
}
```

Comment: Upvote for `onUserLeaveHint` because it's a more suitable function for what OP wants to achieve compared to `onPause`, an edge case can be activities which will be shown over lock screen and some devices might call `onPause` when trying to show unlock pattern for example

Answer (score 0):

Declare the menu item like at `MainActivity` level, like this:

```java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private MenuItem overflowItem;

    ...

}
```

Now you should instanciate the object inside the `onCreateOptionsMenu` method, like this:

```java
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    ...

    overflowItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings);
    overflowItem.setVisible(true);
    return true;
}
```

Then you can use the `onPause` method to set the overflowItem not visible anymore:

```java
@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    overflowItem.setVisible(false);
}
```

Finally remember to replace your `MenuItem item` object with `overflowItem` where it is used.

Comment: No. This removes only the text but not the overflow menu window.

Comment: can you provide me with some screenshot, of what you are trying to achive?

Comment: i have attached the screenshot. I need to dismiss the overflow menu window. [which is showing settings] when home button is pressed.

Comment: any idea? @Fates

Answer (score 0):

To dismiss the overflow menu you can simply call `closeOptionsMenu()` inside Activity.

[closeOptionsMenu()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#closeOptionsMenu())

> Progammatically closes the options menu. If the options menu is
> already closed, this method does nothing.

You can call it in onPause() method like below:

```
@Override
public void onPause() {
   super.onPause();
   closeOptionsMenu();
}
```

or in case you want to call it only when the user presses the Home key you can use `onUserLeaveHint()` like below:

```
@Override
protected void onUserLeaveHint() {
  super.onUserLeaveHint();
  closeOptionsMenu();
}
```